# Cross platform code sharing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, metalkit

I have an app created from Xcode 9 / New Project / Cross Platform Game App, targets: macOS and iOS.

I wrote the following simple function to load text from a Data Asset.

```
func dataAssetAsString(_ name: String) -> String? {
  if let asset = NSDataAsset(name: NSDataAsset.Name(name)) {
    return String(data: asset.data, encoding: .utf8)
  }
  return nil
}
```

I'm puzzled by the following things:

- This function only works if I import either UIKit, or AppKit.
- But *somehow* importing MetalKit instead of UIKIt or AppKit makes it work. This really puzzles me. This should have nothing to do with MetalKit.

Most answers I found for code sharing between iOS and macOS suggest some kind of conditional import at the beginning of the file / shimming.

I went through the slides of [WWDC 2014 Session 233: Sharing code between iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/233/), and it explicitly says we should not do shimming in Swift.

[image: swift shimming no]

On the other hand, I don't understand what we *should* do instead of shimming. The mentioned very complicated process of creating and compiling shared frameworks for a 5 line function cannot be the right direction.

1. In 2018 (Swift 4, Xcode 9, iOS 11, macOS 10.13), what would be the recommended way to add such a trivial cross platform code to an app?
2. What is the magic of MetalKit which makes it work without shimming? Does it shim internally?

Comment: It looks like you [got an answer to this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/95999) on the Apple developer forums—consider writing your type alias solution up as an answer to your own question here.